# docker compose command with multiline batch command fails with if statement

Tags: batch-file, docker-compose, cmd

I have a docker compose file with a windows container service.
The command section takes a multiline batch command.

```
command:>     
 cmd /c "
      if "%build%"=="release" (
      cd some_dir ) else (cd other_dir) &&
      7z.exe a some_z * &&
      last_command & exit 0 "
```

with the if statement the multiline batch command always fails. Does anyone know why ? Thanks.

Comment: Please copy/paste to avoid typos. Batch can be sensitive to layout. `"build"` will never be equal to `"release"` You probaly need `%build%` (the *contents* of the variable `build`). Whether it's expressed that way in Dorker, I've no idea.

Comment: can you try the if statement with just a single quotes. `if 'build'=='release'`

Comment: Do `some_dir` and `other_dir` exist? What is the current directory?

Comment: Yes for sure because I manually copied them in.  I was just wondering if this was a known issue and you can chain an if statement in batch.

Comment: The statement itself is good. You can try to replace `cd` commands with `echo` and see if it goes inside `if` statement. I can only imagine that the directories are not found so `if` statement fails and hence && doesn't go further.